# Почему Resultset обрезается?

Tags: jdbc, java, sql-server

Суть проблемы при обращении к хранимой процедуре клиента получаю два Resultset. С первым все хорошо, но вот второй состоит из 20 строк, разработчики клиента утверждают что процедура возвращает около 1000.

```
 Connect connectObject = new Connect();
    Connection connectionToPool = null;
    CallableStatement procedure = null;
    ResultSet table = null;
    int rowCounter;
    SOATO answer = new SOATO();
    int counter = 1;

    try {
        connectObject.init(POOL);
        connectionToPool = connectObject.getConnection();

        procedure = connectionToPool.prepareCall("{call procedure()}");
        procedure.execute();

        while (true) {
            rowCounter = procedure.getUpdateCount();

            if (rowCounter > 0) {             // This  is update counter
                procedure.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }

            if (rowCounter == 0) {   // DDL command or 0 updates
                procedure.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }

            table = procedure.getResultSet();     // If we reached here, we have a    
                                                 //   set of data, or no more results
            if (table != null) {
                switch (counter) {
                    case 1:                 // Area tables
                        answer.areaDataHandler(table);
                        counter++;
                        break;

                    case 2:                // Region tables
                        answer.regionDataHandler(table);
                        counter++;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                procedure.getMoreResults();
                continue;
            }
            break;                              // No more results
        }
    }
```

`regionDataHandler()` аналогичен `areaDataHandler()`

```
public void areaDataHandler(ResultSet table) throws SQLException {
    while (table.next()) {
        Area temp = new Area();
        temp.setKodobl(table.getInt("kodobl"));
        temp.setNameobl(table.getString("nameobl"));
        area.add(temp);
    }
}
```

База данных MSSQL 2000, использовался сторонний jdbc драйвер ибо мелкомягкие прекратили поддержку 2000, а драйвер к этой версии бд изъяли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправлено!

Проблема была вызвана переполнением int поля в принимающем классе. Найти проблему помогло введение более корректного журналирования ошибок в приложении.

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` может изменяться по ходу действия пьесы. Это управляется флагом: `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` или `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` - читайте документацию.

Более того:

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.

Вам надо уточнить у разработчиков хранимой процедуры касаемо вашего `ResultSet`, а именно касаемо флагов изоляции и начального позиционирования указателя курсора. Иногда таки полезно перед началом цикла `ResultSet.next()` выставить: `ResultSet.beforeFirst()`

Comment: Разработчики процедуры утверждают, что при её разработке использовали 
все дефолтные настройки(грубо говоря  согласно базовым тоториалам). Так что курсор по идеи находится на первой строке(да и выводимые данные соответствуют первым, выводимым селектом).
Про beforeFirst()не совсем понял, у меня его добавление приводит к тому, что приложение вообще не находит ни одной строки и table.getRow() возвращает 0.